# I am struggling with this recursively building tree

Tags: java, recursion, tree

Fairly new to Java, i am trying to build a tree in a recursive function. I will just post the code first:

```
public static void buildpreorder(TreeNode node, int layer){
    if (layer == stops){
        return;
    }
    else{
        int n=0;
        // for loop in order to iterate through visited[] array
        for(int i=0; i<stops;i++){ 


            if (node.visited[i]==true){ // Checks if node was already visited

                node.children[n]= new TreeNode(Ziele[i+1], layer, stops, count, node.visited, node);
                node.visited[i]=false;

            }
            count++;

            buildpreorder(node.children[n], layer+1);
            n++;

            }
        }
        return;
    }
 }
```

So i try to pass down the visited[] array so that the lower nodes know which Nodes have to be created. This works fine until the point where the first return of the recursion takes place. Then the visited array stays completely false. Even though i save the visited[] in the class of the node it doesn't work.

Oh and the TreeNode code is here, maybe than it is clearer:

```
 public TreeNode(String destination, int layer, int max, int count, boolean[] tovisit, TreeNode parent){
    this.destination=destination;
    this.layer=layer;
    this.count=count;
    this.parent=parent;
    if (max-layer == 0){
        this.children= new TreeNode[1];
    }
    else{
        this.children= new TreeNode[max-layer];
    }

    this.visited= new boolean[max]; //visited[] gets copied from parent node
    for (int i=0; i< max; i++){
        this.visited[i]=tovisit[i];
    }
}
```

The wanted tree is a "symmetric" tree (don't know what to call it). in the first layer the is one root with 6 nodes, on each node 5 next nodes. on each of the 5 nodes are four other nodes, so on and so on..

```
  0                  Start
                      . . .
                  .     .      .
                .       .        .
  1          A          B          C
            . .        . .        .  .            
           .   .      .    .     .    .
  2       B    C      A    C     A     B
          .    .      .    .     .     .
          .    .      .    .     .     .
  3       C    B      C    A     B     A
```

The visited array is supposed to keep track of the status of this branch. In the added example the visited array at the first B in the second layer {0,0,1}. So next time a node is created, it knows where to go. The problem is that the visited array is not conserved in each function. So when the method returns, the old visited[] misses. After the method touches the first leaf (first C, third layer) the method completely comes to the top again with the visited[]={0,0,0}

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Is the `visited` array supposed to represent a single branch of the tree? Once you've created each node on one branch, wouldn't you need an entirely new array to create the next branch?

Comment: where does `stop` and `count` come from in your static `buildpreorder` function? And why do you use an extra index `n`? Can you be more specific about what you trying to accomplish? Only creating a 1-4-3-2-1 like structure?

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but the whole point of a tree is to not do this.  You may as well sort your input and then just use a binary search.  Look into balanced trees (they're "symmetric") and B-trees.

Comment: @PaulHicks the visited array is used to build the tree and to keep track of which node (A,B,C) have to be visited yet.

Comment: @MadMatts "stops" means how the amount of nodes for example {A,B,C}= 3 stops. The tree should be created with the criteria that each branch has to have all stops(A,B,C) included. Later on these nodes get a "price" and than the cheapest way is calculated.

Comment: so `stops` is your value attribute for each node? How many nodes must a node have? Does this depend on it's level?

Comment: @madMatts Stops is The iterative for the the value of nodes, the value comes from Ziele[]. Yes, it absolutely depends on the level, that is the point here

Comment: @MadMatts the children of a node gets determined with stops-layer. So in the upper example stops would be 3 (ABC) & layer starts with zero